# Adding role to AspNetUserRoles table in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I use `ASP.NET Identity 2.0` in my `MVC` application and I want to assign 2 default roles to the user who login to the system for the first time by adding 2 records to the **AspNetUserRoles** table with `UserId` and `RoleId`. Is there a practical way to to this? Or do I have to add these default roles using `DBContext` and `Entity Framework`, etc. (I use `EF Code First`)? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

After creating the user record in Register post action

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

You can add the roles

```
await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "role1");
await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "role2");
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. The oles can be assigned, but I cannot create new user in **AspNetUsers** table by using the first part of your code. Could you have a look at please?

Comment: On the other hand, I also need to add these new roles to the AspNetUserRoles  table, but I am not sure if your code can also perform this.

Comment: @binary The first two lines of code are from default mvc5 template, thats how a new ApplicationUser / IdentityUser is inserted in database. The other two lines of code assign user to those roles, using asp.net-identity. In database inside AspNetUserRoles you will see two new entries {userId and role1Id} and {userId and role2Id}

Answer (score 1):

You could do a check in the AccountController, Register method (the one with the HttpPost), something like: `if (!MyDbContext.Users.Any()) {...}`

And if there are no users, assign roles to the newly created user with: `UserManager.AddToRoleAsync`